# How to setup domain name to my Windows 2008 Server VPS Hosting?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, vps

I just purchased **VPS Window Server 2008 Hosting**, from SoftSys Hosting, Already setups IIS server, so that now I am  able to access my website through IP address assigned to my server.

I am already having a domain name registered from GoDady, So now the question is:

**How to Setup my Domain name to my VPS Server?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point A record of your domain to your VPS.

You can get more & proper help regarding this from your registrar(i.e. GoDady).

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a stack overflow (i.e. "programming") question.

But the answer's really simple: you usually get a domain when you get your VPS.  Your provider (Godaddy?!?  What were you thinking! ;)) will tell you what (if anything) you need to do to point your domain to your server.  Usually, it's just done automagically for you.

Comment: No, Problem here is my hosting is from different company and domain is registered from different host, so didn't getting any help on this.

I was just wondering if some buddy on Stackoverflow help me.

Comment: Whoever sold you the domain should be able to tell you how to set an "A", "MX" etc DNS records to point to whatever server you want.  Don't let them cash the check until they tell you ;)

Comment: Yes i followed these step to add record like 'A', 'MX'. Here is the link: http://members.softsyshosting.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=57

I Followed these steps as it is, now not getting what i have to do next?

Comment: Hey buddy, i think i have to do these name server setup at my vps server, then after that same configuration to my domain management panel at Go-daddy. Please let me know your thoughts on it.